# Unable to implement control on MoveIt: Parameter '~moveit_controller_manager' not specified

Tags: ros, moveit, joint-trajectory-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am struggling to implement a joint_trajectory_controller on Moveit.

I have:

1. Set up my controllers.yaml file

```
controller_list:
       - name: /nymble_arm_controller
         action_ns: joint_trajectory_action
         type: FollowJointTrajectory
         default: true
         joints:
             - base_swivel
             - arm_joint
             - elbow_joint  
             - wrist_pitch
             - wrist_yaw
             - wrist_roll
```

2.Implemented an action server node for joint_trajectory_action interface.

Action server I have implemented is from [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/192739/implement-moveit-on-real-robot/)

3.Created a moveit_planning_execution launch file as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_MoveIt_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot)

This launch file contains the required controller_manager.launch file described [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/src/doc/controller_configuration.html)

4.Created a launch file to start action server and included above launch file.

I have gone through all the similar questions asked before but none has helped me.

Will be grateful for some help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237157/unable-to-implement-control-on-moveit:-parameter-%27%7Emoveit_controller_manager%27-not-specified/) by [rohin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26768/rohin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2016-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The mistake I was making was that the controller.launch file was not named in the following convention:

"robotname"_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml

---

Originally posted by [rohin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26768/rohin/) with karma: 99 on 2016-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0